# Counting value list items in FileMaker

Tags: frequency, filemaker, self-join, counting, summary

Please see link to FileMaker Pro 12 database I've created to illustrate my problem:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24821795/Example.fmp12

I want to count the number of times an Activity has been assigned to a Staff member, but there are a couple of things making it tricky (not impossible, I hope):

1. When the user performs a Find, the count should update to only include the found records.
2. The user can add to the list of activities.

In the example provided, SelfJoinCount and Activities::Count are not what I want - they both count Activity (e.g. Archery has been assigned to two staff members), but do not meet criteria 1. above.

Try performing a Find of Gender = M

- The values of ReviewedCount (a summary field, counting Reviewed) change to 3, which is what I want.
- The values of SelfJoinCount and Activities::Count do not change. In this case, I want them to change to 1 (i.e. One record with Ballooning, one record with Bird watching and one record with Archery in the found set).

I could create a calculation field with a 1 in it if the activity occurs and then a summary field counting that 1 for every single activity in the database, BUT this won't work because of criteria 2. above (also, there are a lot of activities).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, several problems you have here.

First, you need key values for your tables. This can easily be accomplished by creating a number field in each table. In the options, select auto-enter serial number, validation unique, not empty.

Now, you need a 3rd table for the join. This table will have the foreign key value for the Staff member as well as the foreign key for the activity.

You will want to have your Staff layout in form view, add a portal into the join table with they foreign key field for the activity. Create a popup or drop down list for activities (hint: if you want the name of the activity to show in the layout rather than its key, use a popup.) it needs to have they key value and display second field, all values, show only value from second field.

This will allow you to have a many to many relationship between the tables so that a single staff member can have many activities and an activity can have many staff members.

Now, if you want a count of each activity, you could of course create calculation fields in the staff table to count instances of each activity type, but I find that cumbersome and time consuming as well as requiring you to create TO's for each activity. What you really want to use is an ExecuteSQL() function. Some thing like this:

ExecuteSQL("

SELECT COUNT(J.FK_ActivityID)
FROM JoinTable J
WHERE J.FK_StaffID =?
Group by J.FK_ActivityID";"";"";Staff::PK_StaffID)

You can tweak that ExecuteSQL to include a specific activity, or leave it as it is an include them all. Up to you how you do it.

If it wasn't 7am and having had no sleep, I would mock up the file for you, but I think you would do better testing it and working on it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, but I don't think it addresses the caveats 1. and 2. in my original post. Also, my apologies for not thinking to mention these things:

* this will be for a runtime solution, so it can't use ExecuteSQL.

* there will be multiple databases to be merged, so activities cannot have key values associated with them

Comment: With the extra table and portal you seem to have laid out a solution for adding multiple activities to a staff member - this isn't required. Each staff member only has one activity assigned and I just want a count of the number of times an activity was assigned to any staff member (but with the caveats I mentioned in the original post).

> you could of course create calculation fields in the staff table ...

I can't, because the user can add to the list of activities, so I can't add a TO for each activity.

Comment: Having multiple databases to merge does in no way restrict you being able to key your tables. In fact, it is even more important that you do so as to keep correct information in the correct records.

Unfortunately, you had no mentioned a runtime solution or I would not have brought up ExecuteSQL.

For your instance, if you just want to count how many times an activity is assigned, create a calculation (valuecount(list(staff)) in the activity table and view the counts from there.

Comment: I tried valuecount(list(staff)) - it behaves in exactly the same way as the two counts in my example i.e. Doesn't meet caveat 1.

Comment: ok, you've even gotten me confused here....

you want to be able to perform a find on the staff table for something like Gender = M and you want to see how many times a specific activity has been assigned to that gender?

Comment: I want to perform any Find operation and have the counts update for the subset of found records (the way a summary field behaves).

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wesrbmtjl3s0cb6/Example.fmp12

Here's how it works. You have a calculated field in the staff table which just takes fields you want and turn then into a return delimited list. In the Activities table, you have a global field that you can set with a value of your choosing.

You have a TO that relates Activites to Staff by Activity Name and by the global field --> calculated list.

On the layout Activities Report, you can enter a value in the filter field such as M or F and hit enter and you will see your values update.

Comment: You are going to run into issues later on though. If the group has a staff issue (someone missing, quit etc) and they do actually need to assign a second activity to a staff member, they wont be able to. Also, you need to key your tables. Even if that means you need to key the tables in the other databases too.